# AWS EMR - Terminated with errors On the master instance application provisioning failed

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-emr, terraform-provider-aws

I'm provisioning an EMR cluster **emr-5.30.0**. I run this using Terraform and get the following error on AWS CONSOLE as it fails.

> Amazon EMR Cluster j-11I5FOBxxxxxx has terminated with errors at 2020-10-26 19:51 UTC with a reason of BOOTSTRAP_FAILURE.

I don't have any bootstrap steps. I can't view any logs either to see what is happening. Log URI is blank and can't SSH to cluster too since it's terminated.

**Any pointers would be appreciated?**

**Providing AWS-CLI-EXPORT output:**

> aws emr create-cluster --auto-scaling-role EMR_AutoScaling_DefaultRole --applications Name=Spark --tags 'Account=xxx' 'Function=xxx' 'Repository=' 'Mail=xxx@xxx.com' 'Slack=xxx' 'Builder=xxx' 'Environment=xxx' 'Service=xxx xxx xxx' 'Team=xxx' 'Name=xxx-xxx-xxx' --ebs-root-volume-size 100 --ec2-attributes '{"KeyName":"xxx","AdditionalSlaveSecurityGroups":[""],"InstanceProfile":"EMR_EC2_DefaultRole","ServiceAccessSecurityGroup":"sg-xxx","SubnetId":"subnet-xxx","EmrManagedSlaveSecurityGroup":"sg-xxx","EmrManagedMasterSecurityGroup":"sg-xxx","AdditionalMasterSecurityGroups":[""]}' --service-role EMR_DefaultRole --release-label emr-5.30.0 --name 'xxx-xxx-xxx' --instance-groups '[{"InstanceCount":1,"EbsConfiguration":{"EbsBlockDeviceConfigs":[{"VolumeSpecification":{"SizeInGB":32,"VolumeType":"gp2"},"VolumesPerInstance":4}]},"InstanceGroupType":"MASTER","InstanceType":"m5.2xlarge","Name":""},{"InstanceCount":2,"EbsConfiguration":{"EbsBlockDeviceConfigs":[{"VolumeSpecification":{"SizeInGB":40,"VolumeType":"gp2"},"VolumesPerInstance":1}]},"InstanceGroupType":"CORE","InstanceType":"m5.2xlarge","Name":""}]' --configurations '[{"Classification":"hadoop-env","Properties":{},"Configurations":[{"Classification":"export","Properties":{"PYSPARK_PYTHON":"/usr/bin/python3","JAVA_HOME":"/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0"}}]},{"Classification":"spark-env","Properties":{},"Configurations":[{"Classification":"export","Properties":{"PYSPARK_PYTHON":"/usr/bin/python3","JAVA_HOME":"/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0"}}]}]' --scale-down-behavior TERMINATE_AT_TASK_COMPLETION --region eu-west-2

Comment: Are you trying to Create EMR cluster inside a Private Subnet?

Answer (score 4):

Issue was due to JAVA_HOME incorrectly set.
`JAVA_HOME":"/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0"`

Resolution: Check logs in S3 under: provision-node/reports and it should tell you which bootstrap step fails...

Comment: Set "JAVA_HOME": "/etc/alternatives/jre" resolved my issue

Comment: FWIW, my issue was bintray stopped serving up Scala Build Tool! ;D https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues/6445

Answer (score 0):

Building a cluster with emr-6.2.0 on md5.xlarge, this is JAVA_HOME:
/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-amazon-corretto.x86_64

Comment: Please explain why should the user do this, and point to references/websites if you have some.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error.

```
Terminated with errors
On the master instance (i-00f80ba5bed7f7aac), application provisioning failed
```

Following this guide.

https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/emr-application-provisioning-error

I found this error inside app-phase, i.e. puppet's stderr logs.

```
2023-11-19 04:15:04,560 INFO BigtopPuppeteer: setConfig reportdir: /var/log/provision-node/reports/0/82133c07-d6c4-4e8a-bbe3-1ec80befd943
2023-11-19 04:15:07,695 INFO BigtopPuppeteer: Set 1 puppet configs
2023-11-19 04:16:28,670 INFO NodeProvisionerWorkflow: Starting processing puppet report for failure message
2023-11-19 04:16:28,676 INFO DefaultPuppetYamlReportProcessor: Found latest puppet report file /var/log/provision-node/reports/0/82133c07-d6c4-4e8a-bbe3-1ec80befd943/ip-172-31-76-184.ec2.internal/202311190416.yaml
2023-11-19 04:16:28,804 INFO NodeProvisionerWorkflow: Finished processing puppet report for failure message
2023-11-19 04:16:28,848 ERROR Program: Encountered a problem while provisioning
com.amazonaws.emr.node.provisioner.puppet.api.PuppetException: Execution of '/bin/yum -d 0 -e 0 -y --releasever=2 list kernel-devel-4.14.327-246.539.amzn2.x86_64' returned 1: Error: No matching Packages to list
    at com.amazonaws.emr.node.provisioner.workflow.NodeProvisionerWorkflow.work(NodeProvisionerWorkflow.java:160) ~[node-provisioner-2.52.0.jar:?]
    at com.amazonaws.emr.node.provisioner.Program.main(Program.java:31) [node-provisioner-2.52.0.jar:?]
```

When I looked for the current kernel info.

```
[hadoop@ip-172-31-70-193 stubs]$ cat /proc/version
Linux version 4.14.327-246.539.amzn2.x86_64 (mockbuild@ip-10-0-61-37) (gcc version 7.3.1 20180712 (Red Hat 7.3.1-17) (GCC)) #1 SMP Sun Oct 22 17:17:17 UTC 2023
```

I list kernel-devel packages in the yum list, this is what I got. This implies kernel-devel package inside the yum's updated package list is later version than the one installed. And EMR's provisioning phase tries to install  devel package of the kernel which it knows should be present.

```
[hadoop@ip-172-31-70-193 stubs]$ sudo yum check-update -y
Loaded plugins: extras_suggestions, langpacks, priorities, update-motd
14 packages excluded due to repository priority protections

containerd.x86_64                                                 1.7.2-1.amzn2.0.1                                              amzn2extra-docker
kernel.x86_64                                                     4.14.328-248.540.amzn2                                         amzn2-core       
kernel-devel.x86_64                                               4.14.328-248.540.amzn2                                         amzn2-core       
nspr.x86_64                                                       4.35.0-1.amzn2                                                 amzn2-core       
nss.x86_64                                                        3.90.0-2.amzn2.0.1                                             amzn2-core       
nss-softokn.x86_64                                                3.90.0-6.amzn2                                                 amzn2-core
```

The solution is don't `update` in `yum` as it installs latest kernel which implies we need a reboot which we don't do reboot on EMR machines.

```
sudo amazon-linux-extras install 
#sudo yum update -y  # don't run this command as it actually installs updated packages.
sudo yum clean all  
sudo yum check-update 
#sudo yum groupinstall 'Development Tools' -y # DON'T RUN THIS.  
sudo yum install gcc-c++ gcc-gfortran git -y
#OpenBlas already provides liblapack.so ,  so no need to install lapack separately
sudo yum install arpack openblas openblas-devel -y
sudo yum install java-17-amazon-corretto.x86_64 java-17-amazon-corretto-devel.x86_64 -y
```

If you don't run `yum update`, puppet's app-phase will find the both kernel packages since we haven't run an update yet.

```
[hadoop@ip-172-31-70-193 stubs]$ sudo yum list | grep kernel-devel
kernel-devel.x86_64                    4.14.327-246.539.amzn2        @amzn2-core
kernel-devel.x86_64                    4.14.328-248.540.amzn2        amzn2-core
```

Also make sure you are not installing the whole development toolset using line similar to following.

```
## Comment the following line. Install required development tools one by one
#sudo yum groupinstall 'Development Tools' -y
sudo yum install gcc-c++ gcc-gfortran git -y
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to change the instance type and try running it in different AZ and see if problem persists.

Comment: Yep, tried earlier but same error. Diff EC2 instance type and region.